# Where is windows server 2012 container feature

Tags: docker, windows-server, windows-server-container

I have read on some forums and tutorials that windows server offers a containers feature. I suppose this is a kind of "docker" but for windows.
I tried to add the feature in the server manager but the container item is not available.
Is it because a i need a special edition or version of windows server ?

Or is there a way to download the feature ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container feature is only available starting with Windows Server 2016 which is not released yet but you can test it with the technical preview versions of it

See the [FAQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/faq) for it:

> What are the prerequisites for Windows Server Containers and Hyper-V
>   Containers?
>
> Both Window Server Containers and Hyper-V Containers require Windows
>   Server 2016. These technologies will not work with previous versions
>   of Windows.

Comment: Thanks do you know if it works with docker or is it something différent and équivalent ?

Comment: You can manage the windows containers via the docker CLI. I recommend reading the MSDN docs about this feature as there are step by step instructions which also includes installing docker

Comment: Thanks when you talk about docker cli you mean docker client ? Server wont ne docker ?

Comment: windows 2016 has it's own containers equivalent. Microsoft worked with Docker to make it 'compatible' with docker. In this case compatible means that you can use docker tools (cli, registry) with Windows Containers. This solution is for Windows based images (i.e. Nanoserver). For Linux based images you will still need boot to docker like approach (currently official docker for windows available from docker website uses Linux VM in hyper-v).